# planet atmospheric composition

Tags: planets, atmosphere, chemistry

I am been making an alien planet for my xenobiology project, this planet would have an atmospheric pressure of 1.5 atm and it would be composed of the following gases:

- Nitrogen: 83.7%
- Oxygen: 10.4%
- Methane: 3.1%
- Argon: 1.2%
- Water vapor: 1.1%
- Carbon Dioxide: 0.4%

along with some traces gases which include:

- Helium: 0.001%
- Ammonia: 0.005%
- Neon: 0.002%
- Hydrogen Sulfide: 0.002%
- Nitrogen Dioxide: 0.000001%
- Ozone: 0.00005%
- Sulfur Dioxide: 0.00001%
- Krypton: 0.0002%
- Xenon: 0.00001%

would this atmosphere be breathable? And what effects might the gases have on the planet?

edit: after some consideration, I decided to increase the oxygen level to make the atmosphere more breathable, this is what the chemical composition looks like now:

- Nitrogen: 78.1%
- Oxygen: 16%
- Methane: 3.1%
- Argon: 1.4%
- Water vapor: 1.1%
- Carbon Dioxide: 0.15%

I also included trace gases:

- Helium: 0.001%
- Ammonia: 0.005%
- Neon: 0.002%
- Hydrogen Sulfide: 0.002%
- Nitrogen Dioxide: 0.000001%
- Ozone: 0.00005%
- Sulfur Dioxide: 0.00001%
- Krypton: 0.0002%
- Xenon: 0.00001%

I also increased the atmospheric pressure from 1.5 atm to 1.6 atm

edit 2: I also decreased the amount of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere composition above

Comment: I don't know about your trace gases, but studies have found significant cognitive impairment at 0.25% CO2 (and possibly lower, though the data gets less clear.) The high methane and argon content should be safe, I think, though I wouldn't be surprised if continuous exposure to that much methane would have negative health consequences over the long term.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't much of an answer, but this ought to answer your question.
[image]

At 22.5 pounds per square inch, at 10% concentration, the short answer is yes, it's breathable, but barely.